# What does question "Create object representation of following HTML elements" (in python) exactly means?

Tags: python, html, object, representation

I am currently applying for a job, where they ask me this question.
What exactly does "object representation" means? Am I supposed to create object that does exactly the same what HTML element does (ie. Input - do i need co create graphical box into which you can type?)
I am not looking for complete solution, i just would like to know what they want for me.
Should I use html tag? Do you know some libraries you would recommend for this?

(I am aware that i probably won't get this or another similar job soon, but I want to at the very least find solution for this and thus improve myself)

thx alot for any reactions, tips, or tutorials that cover this issue :)

Comment: I assume they just want you to model HTML elements using classes. E.g., define `class HTML: ...`, `class UL: ...`, `class P: ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

They're asking you to recreate the version of JavaScripts DOM in python.

Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

For python you might want to check out: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html